# How to know when a TreeView row is selected in Ruby GTK

Tags: ruby, gtk, gtktreeview

I'm trying to catch the click event on a row

For some reason this only works on double click.

```
@tree.signal_connect("row-activated") do |view, path, column|
    puts "Row #{path.to_str} was clicked!"
end
```

How can I catch just a single click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say :
`@tree.signal_connect("cursor-changed")  { |w,e| selObj(w,e) }`

Answer (score 0):

row-activated is the double-click signal. Think of "activated" as "user wants to edit this or do something with it." If you're using VisualRuby, then any GTK object with a show() method should be editable - it'll pop up its window when double-clicked.

I agree with the answer above - a single click changes the cursor, so use cursor-changed.